# Present Simple or Present Progressive?

Tags: tenses, present-tense, present-progressive, present-continuous

I've got a sentence which claims to use the Present Simple. The source of the sentence is https://en.puzzle-english.com/directory/present-simple-markers where the use of the Present Simple is explained.

> This year we ***propose*** another programme.

Could you please tell me why the Present Simple is more preferable to use here? I think it would be better to use the Present Progressive since it is a temporary situation.

> This year we ***are proposing*** another programme.

Am I not right?

There is another sentence where I, on the contrary, doubt the use of the Present Progressive.

> I'm afraid I can't come. I ***am having*** piano lessons at that time.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? If it is a schedule, why use the Present Progressive, but not Simple?

> I can't come. I ***have*** piano lessons at that time.

Comment: A very sensible question. Firstly, both are grammatical. Secondly, both are idiomatic (sound natural), with the present simple version sounding perhaps more academic/formal, and thus possibly preferable here. You wouldn't expect that version in conversation, though. And a comma (/slight pause in speech) might be expected (though by no means mandatory) with the less formal version. // The present simple is usually worked around in conversation / informal writing, as it tends to sound stilted. // I'll convert this to an 'answer' if I find references I'm happy with, though it may take some time.

Comment: I'm eagerly waiting for your reply. I've added some more details to the question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Both (3) and (4) are grammatical, and mean largely the same thing. I'd suspect more finality, definiteness about the statement in (4) (it's curter). (3) could hint at the fact that the piano lessons have not started at the time of speaking (though this is far from certain), or could hint at a sense of the lessons not being sacrosanct ... even at a desire to 'come' instead. But this is hypothesising about nuances.

Comment: For this year, we're going to propose another programe. Every year, we propose different programmes. I'm afraid I can't come. I have piano lessons at that time. (For no precise reason I know of, I think 'I have' is better than 'I am having'.)